# Canvas - How to load an assets files?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, canvas

I am trying to run a canvas(https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Quick-Start) project in local environment. When it runs, assets are not loading. It is throwing an error like,

```
GET http://localhost:3000/dist/brandable_css/new_styles_normal_contrast/bundles…0checksum.%20you%20need%20to%20run%20./node_modules/.bin/brandable_css.css 
GET http://localhost:3000/dist/brandable_css/new_styles_normal_contrast/bundles…0checksum.%20you%20need%20to%20run%20./node_modules/.bin/brandable_css.css
GET http://localhost:3000/lato-fontfaceobserver.js
GET http://localhost:3000/dist/brandable_css/default/variables-0ca278a9a40f228643ee03728fe584e8.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Also I am not finding `dist/` folder inside a project.

Please help me to solve this assets issue.

Comment: did you run it ~/canvas$ $GEM_HOME/bin/bundle exec rake canvas:compile_assets

Comment: Yes. But then also I am getting some error.

Comment: config.assets.compile = false
  in your development.rb from config folder